# CSS: How to draw vertical line with lables on line

Tags: html, css

I have a homework in CSS.
My job is to draw a route of bus.

This is my html:

```html
<div class="city-group">
  <div class="city-name-wrapper">
    <div class="city-name-line">
      <div class="city-name">City 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="stop-list">
    <div class="stop">Stop 1</div>
    <div class="stop">Stop 2</div>
    <div class="stop">Stop 3</div>
    <div class="stop">Stop 4</div>
    <div class="stop">Stop 5</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="city-group">
 <div class="city-name-wrapper">
    <div class="city-name-line">
      <div class="city-name">City 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="stop-list">
    <div class="stop">Stop 6</div>
    <div class="stop">Stop 7</div>
    <div class="stop">Stop 8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have to style it like [The pircture below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nydHb.jpg):

- Stops are grouped by city.
- Each group has a Vertical bracket on left.
- Rotated label with City name On the bracket line.

I tried this css, but i don't now how to make it work...

Here is link for JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/edm6qrt2/

I prefare to use modern CSS, including flex or grid.
I need suppoort only for Google Chrome.

Thenk's for any help!

Comment: Can you include an example of CSS that you've attempted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use pseduo elements to create the left-most vertical line 
that spans the height of the city group.

Additionally, you could align the `city-name` along that vertical line via a CSS transform, as documented in the code snippet below:

```css
.city-group {
  position:relative;
  /* Create space to left of city group to 
  accomodate the city name and lines */
  padding-left:2rem;
}

/* Define pseudo element for vertical black
line to the left, spanning the vertical axis
of the city group */
.city-group:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  border-left:1px solid black;
  left:.75rem;
  top:1rem;
  bottom:1rem;
  position:absolute;
}

/* Transform the city name with translation and
rotation to place in line with line spanning left
of city group */
.city-name {
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%) rotate(-90deg) translateY(50%);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top:-0.5em;
    border:2px solid orange;
    background:white;
    padding:0 1rem;
    z-index:1;
}

/* Create spacing above/below each stop */
.stop {
  padding:0.5rem 0;
  position:realtive;
}

/* Style pseudo elements for first and last
stop which are the horizontal line segments
for these stops. These line segments connect
with the vertical line defined above */
.stop:first-child:before,
.stop:last-child:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  border-top:1px solid black;
  left:.75rem;
  width:0.75rem;
  position:absolute;
}

/* Offset first line segement from top of
city group */
.stop:first-child:before {
  top:1rem;
}

/* Offset last line segement from bottom of
city group */
.stop:last-child:before {
  bottom:1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="city-group">
    <div class="city-name">
        City 1
    </div>
    <div class="stop-list">
        <div class="stop">Stop 1</div>
        <div class="stop">Stop 2</div>
        <div class="stop">Stop 3</div>
        <div class="stop">Stop 4</div>
        <div class="stop">Stop 5</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="city-group">
    <div class="city-name">
        Long City 2
    </div>
    <div class="stop-list">
        <div class="stop">Stop 6</div>
        <div class="stop">Stop 7</div>
        <div class="stop">Stop 8</div>
        <div class="stop">Stop 9</div>
        <div class="stop">Stop 10</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When i change ths length of city name, the label position is not correct.. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/nLhzsqux/
Please help me again!

Comment: @JudahA sorry about that, just updated answer - hope that helps!

Comment: @dacre-deny, maybe with ```writing-mode: vertical-rl;``` it can be better. I will try it.
thanks you anyway! Your help is very valuable!